# Как взаимодейстовать с таблмцами,связанными OneToOneField в Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model

я совсем новичок в этом деле, поэто прошу отнестись с пониманием)
К сожалению не могу предоставить код, из за невозможности его выноса с работы(
Задача такова: есть две таблицы данных (модели)"рабочее место" и "компьютер".В таблице "рабочее место" находятся такие колонки как "номер", "перечень оборудования" и "номер компьютера". И вот именно "номер компьютера" связан с другой таблицей ("компьютер") в которой также присутствует колонка " номер компьютера", а  также "конфигурация". Пользователю предлогается заполнить форму " Создать рабочее место", в которой необходимо заполнить соответствующие колонки,среди которых есть колонка "номер". В ней НУЖНО предложить привязать уже существующий номер компьютера(подозревпю выпадающим списком) из таблицы(модели) "Компьютер", а если такого нет, то вписать в это поле свой номер,а после сохранить запись в базе. Если пользователь ввел номер компьютера, которого нет, то в связанной таблице(модели) "Компьютер" создается запись с едмнственным заполненым полем "номер компьютера", который должен соответстовать тому номеру, который зада пользователь.